# What is soft voting in KNN?

Tags: statistics, machine-learning

I understand how k-nearest-neighbours (KNN) works, but I am unfamiliar with the term "soft-voting". What is soft voting in relation to KNN and how does it work compared to standard KNN voting?

A simple example comparing the two voting schemes would be useful and a link to a Matlab implementation would be a nice bonus.

Thanks

Josh

Comment: Try posting this question in the [stats.SE](http://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some reading, I discovered that soft-voting simply places a Gaussian at each of the points (training examples) that are being voted on.

Ordinarily, we would simply vote for training examples that are the closest in the feature space, usually by adding one to the votes of the nearest neighbour(s). Instead, soft-voting simply uses the Gaussian probability of all training examples as a voting score, and accumulates the respective votes based on each score. This simply provides a more robust voting scheme as it is more cognisant of relative distances, particularly in higher dimensional spaces.

For more details, refer to Mitchell et al. A “soft” K-nearest neighbor voting scheme, 2001.

For an example of where it has been used, see Agarwal et al. Recovering 3D Human Pose from Monocular Images, 2005